# Bluetooth controller profiles

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

In `bluetoothctl`, if I run `show` on my default bluetooth controller, I get the following:

```
Controller XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        Name: computer-name
        Alias: computer-name
        Class: 0x00010c
        Powered: yes
        Discoverable: no
        Pairable: yes
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0517
        Discovering: no
```

Where are supported bluetooth profiles, such as A/V Remote Control, set? is that coming from the firmware of my USB bluetooth adapter or from somewhere in the bluez stack?  Can I change a config file to support a new profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the additional bluetooth profiles can be added by the programs that offer the appropriate functionality.  So if I set up a bluetooth OBEX server on my computer, then the output of the `show` command of the `bluetoothctl` has a bunch of new lines:

```
Controller XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
        Name: computer-name
        Alias: computer-name
        Class: 0x10010c
        Powered: yes
        Discoverable: no
        Pairable: yes
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
        Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0517
        Discovering: no
```

The first time I set this up, I did something like the following steps (after pairing, but before connecting):

```
sudo killall bluetoothd
sudo bluetoothd --compat
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
bt-obex -s [/path/to/receiving/directory]
```

However, now I just seem to need to run the last step, which actually starts the OBEX server.  I'm not sure the other steps were even necessary now.